# Manually set the properties of new objects created from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, datagridview

premise: I have a class "User" which has a property of type list to represent a list of "Office" associated with the user.

I have a BindingSource associated to the list of "Office" in which the grid is hooked to insert new elements.

Everything seems to work correctly, when I click on the new line and write a value in the list is added to the new object "Office"

The problem is that in addition to the data entered by the user I want to insert some default value automatically (example: a guid), I know I could do this with a hidden column in my grid, but I do not like too much as a solution and I would like to work directly on the object .

I tried with the event

```
DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This is called after the new object "office" was added to the list but I can not recover it, because I do not know which row is inserted but only a generic word "ItemAdded"

I also tried using the method

```
DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultvaluesneeded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

but this to me is called before my object "office" I is added to the list and I have no way to have it in order to set the default.

Long story short: how do I manually set the values on the properties of an object added to a list automatically from gridview without using hidden columns?

Comment: Why can't you just add a property `Guid guid=Guid.NewGuid();` to the Office class?

Comment: there already, me generates entity framework, the problem is not how to set a guid , but how to set a value on a property of an object that automatically generates the gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Property "guid" is generated from the Entity Framework, then you can add a partial class such as:

```
public partial class Office
{
   public Office()
   {
        guid=Guid.newGuid();
   }
}
```

and add a constructor there which populates the guid property whenever a new office is created.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already created a partial class, the problem is that I do not know that constructor uses the gridview when creating the new object. I also need to check if entity framework allows to define a constructor in a partial class. Obviously over the guid I have other property to be set

Comment: The constructor in the partial class works, i just checked that in the project i am working on

Comment: tonight I can just check whether the gridview when I instantiate a new object "Office" goes into default constructor ;)